# JFlex restricted single line comment regex

Tags: java, regex, comments, jflex

I'm building a lexer for a made up language, and I have a problem with defining the single line comment regex.

The problem is that the comment's allowed characters are restricted. Only some characters are allowed, and they include: whitespaces, digits, letters, and a few symbols (let's say `*`,`/`,`+`,`-`). A single line comment is beginning (as in C and Java) with `//`, and its definition (except the restricted characters) is the same as in C and Java.

At first I have tried the following regex:

`"//" ([a-zA-Z0-9] | [*] | [/] | [+] | [-] | [ \t\f])* (\r|\n|\r\n)`

That would have hopefully caught the single line comments, but unfortunately this doesn't catch a single line comment that is at the end of file, since it doesn't have a line terminator at the end.

I tried to change it to:

`"//" ([a-zA-Z0-9] | [*] | [/] | [+] | [-] | [ \t\f])* ((\r|\n|\r\n) | [^.])`

Hopefully, the `[^.]` would have catch the fact that there are no characters allowed after the comment (someway to emulate `EOF`?) but that didn't work, and the regex is catching everything until a chararcter that is forbidden, for example: `// comment = 1` is translated to `single line comment`,`=`,`1`.

I can't use the JFlex's `<<EOF>>` since it can't be part of a regex.

Is there a good **regex** solution to this problem? (Assuming that I cannot modify the input).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the jflex manual here:
http://jflex.de/manual.html#Example

```
TraditionalComment   = "/*" [^*] ~"*/" | "/*" "*"+ "/"
// Comment can be the last line of the file, without line terminator.
EndOfLineComment     = "//" {InputCharacter}* {LineTerminator}?
DocumentationComment = "/**" {CommentContent} "*"+ "/"
CommentContent       = ( [^*] | \*+ [^/*] )*
```

Also note, you can use a specific eof value using %eofval, also discussed in the manual I posted above.

I realize you're specifically asking for a regex solution, but there also might be a better way to simplify this problem through use of your lexical states - you could have the symbol "//" indicate the entrance to a comment state; once in that state, you can grab all alphanumeric characters until you hit the end of line terminator for a single line, return a tag.comment token, and then transition back to the yyinitial state and continue on lexing.

For example, including everything I've discussed above:

```
%%
%state COMMENT
%%
%eofval{
    return getToken(tag.EOF, null);
%eofval}


comment = "//"
eol = "\r\n\"
characters = [a-zA-Z0-9] | [*] | [/] | [+] | [-]
%%
<YYINITIAL> {comment}{
    yybegin(COMMENT);
    return getToken(tag.Comment, yytext());
}

<COMMENT> {characters}{eol}{
    yybegin(YYINITIAL);
}
```

**disclaimer, this is incomplete as a lexer and done off the top of my head. This is more to demonstrate my example discussed above